# Command to see files ignored by the .gitignore

Tags: git

How can I get a list of all the files and directories currently ignored by git, via a `.gitignore` file (or files with the same functionality, if there are any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

```
git status --ignored
```